# Customize the display of the item picker - SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I have an external content type feeding my external list and in it I have a picker as pictured.

[image]

The numbers don't mean much by themselves. Is there a way I can customize this to show the number and the name?

Answer (score 0):

The data is already bound to the picker at this point which I don't think you can make any change to it.  The only way I can think of changing it is coming from the source, which will be in your Read Item and Read List operations.  You might need to write your own set of stored procedures and combine name and number there so when it's ready for BCS it will be bounded to the data you want to display.  Hope this helps!